# Fast forward / backward on iPod Touch

Tags: ipod-touch

Is there an easy way (that I didn't find yet) the move quickly from one place to another while listen to a podcast or a song (as it was possible on my provious iPod Nano whith the "wheel" button) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tap the album artwork to bring up the seek slider. You can then drag the slider to move from one place to another in the track.

Comment: Also: In iOS 4 and newer, you can move your finger farther above or below the slider (without taking it off the screen) to scroll faster or slower.

Comment: I wonder why there are waiting to have the wheel gesture made available on touch screen. This was really a better way to navigate !

Answer (score 0):

Hold the skip forward/backwards button (Other known as "next song" button) for a few seconds. You'll fast forward/backwards in the song.